# How do I add null exception to regex statement C#

Tags: c#, exception, null

How do I add the exception of null or allow the value null to the following regex statement?

@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}a-zA-Z0-9{2}[A-Za-z0-9]$|[^\x00-\x80]|\b\w{1,1}\b";

Comment: you can't detect a null reference with regex, it has no sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with what you mean by `NULL`. In most programming languages it means no pointer, no reference, unassigned, or even 'zero'. An empty string is not `NULL`, typically. There is a character in the ASCII table for `NULL` at codepoint 0 so your idea of doing `\x00` would detect the `NULL` character.

If you want to allow for a string to be null or empty *or* match the regex, I'd suggest breaking up the operations like so...

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern)) {
    // null or match. do stuff...
}
```

Try this to illustrate the point...

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = "";
string s3 = "\x0";

if (s1 == s2) Console.WriteLine("s1 == s2");
if (s1 == s3) Console.WriteLine("s1 == s3");
if (s2 == s3) Console.WriteLine("s2 == s3");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `(...)?` to match also empty strings. You can't pass null as text input to `Regex.Ismatch()` or `Regex.Matches()`

```
var r=new Regex(@"(^[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}a-zA-Z0-9{2}[A-Za-z0-9]$|[^\x00-\x80]|\b\w{1,1}\b)?");
```

`var isMatchWhenEmpty = r.IsMatch(string.Empty);` // returns **true**

`var result = r.IsMatch(null);` //throws **NullReferenceException**

So add extra validation :

```
var isMatch = string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || r.IsMatch(input);
```